# Estimation of GARCH vs ARCH models

Tags: time-series, estimation, garch

Wikipedia explains the basic specification of these models pretty neatly [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity). In further reading on the actual estimation of these models (MLE appears to be the norm), I have read that the GARCH model has only three parameters that allow for an infinite number of squared roots to influence the conditional variance - I imagine [whoever wrote this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_GARCH_and_ARCH) refers to a GARCH(1,1).

More precisely, if I were to estimate both ARCH and GARCH models without a package but code them myself (nevermind the software), how would they differ?

Comment: I think some time series textbooks or lecture notes should have pseudo-codes for estimation of ARCH and GARCH models, or at least explicit likelihood expressions. It could be easier to find them than to write them from scratch (or explain here). Have you tried looking them up yet?

Comment: @RichardHardy have tried, but most explain the models in a similar fashion to what can be found in Wikipedia and just go further to show examples of estimations. Could you recommend a specific paper or textbook?

Comment: Not from the top of my head, unfortunately. I would have to search myself. Perhaps Hamilton "Time Series Analysis" or Tsay "Analysis of Financial Time Series" or (probably less likely) Lutkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis". Hey, there is one more that should be quite comprehensive: Francq & Zakoïan "GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications".

Comment: @RichardHardy I edited this question to eliminate this potential problem. Thank you

Comment: Great job! I will see if I can find the time to answer, but at least now you have a reasonably well-formulated question.

Comment: Alvaro, what do you think about my answer to your other questions on parsimony?

Comment: I like it :) I am beginning to see how I could go about answering this question too.